# How to search in elasticsearch indexes starting with a string

Tags: elasticsearch

I am still new with elasticsearch and trying to find the best way how to filter results from a range of indices.

i.e.: Filebeat and logstash use to create index per day. I use to use bot for an different purpose and parallel I am using a posix shell script which is parsing and indexing some files from archive. Hence I have 3 types of indexes:

- archive
- logs
- processing

archive and logs are generated with date in the name:

- archive-2015.12.31
- archive-2016.01.04
- logs-2015.12.31
- logs-2016.01.04

I have tried various of attempts, but no success.

How to build the URI if I want to search only in logs or only in archive?

Many thanks 
Regards
Reddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wildcards in the index name. If you want to search all documents in indices whose name start with "logs", the corresponding query is:

```
POST logs*/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

Read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's weird. It is one of first thing I have tried and didn't work. Now it is working. Something weird sits between my keyboard and chair :) Thank you again! Reddy